# Why Find and Replace window is so Wide in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, size, replace

Good afternoon

is there anyone who noticed that **Find and Replace** window each time is getting wider when coding and compiling?

[alt text http://lh4.ggpht.com/_bCvG6V5JTUk/TBEW6w-Tt8I/AAAAAAAAALo/hfXbcl83h2s/wide-find-replace.png](http://lh4.ggpht.com/_bCvG6V5JTUk/TBEW6w-Tt8I/AAAAAAAAALo/hfXbcl83h2s/wide-find-replace.png)

Even when I resize this window in Visual Studio 2010, it gets wider again... :-(

Perhaphs is there a way to fix its size?

Comment: Visual Studio should have moved to Firefox-style F&R years and years ago (eg, an embedded F&R on the main window, that can be expanded if you need to do something "fancy" like regex F&R. I was so disappointed to find the same clunky dialog box in 2010 that's been there since the Pleistocene.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a [Microsoft Connect issue on this](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/558149/find-and-replace-dialog-gets-wider-each-time-it-opens), and the issue was closed, saying:

> The Find Dialog growing is a known
>   issue that we will be fixing for SP1.
>
> Thanks,
>   Weston Hutchins
>   Program Manager - VS Platform
>   http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio

There's actually a couple other [duplicate](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/557087/find-and-replace-dialog-grows-in-width-every-time-it-is-used) [cases](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/561760/find-dialog-gets-wider-each-time-you-do-edit-quick-find-ctrl-f), but no posted workarounds.

I don't know how long it will be until SP1 comes out.  The answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2800348/visual-studio-2010-service-pack-1/2800377#2800377) suggests 6-11 months after release, which would put it at October 2010, at the earliest.

---

The "workaround" that I'm currently using is to simply dock the Find and Replace window in the IDE (I personally put it on the left side under the toolbox).  Obviously, this doesn't allow the window to widen every time you use it.

Comment: Nice link Mark! Indeed there are a lot of issues closed, like the inability of resolving lambda expressions on Immediate window. I think they were in hurry, perhaps because they wanted to release VS2010 anyway.

Comment: Awesome justification for that 30 inch LCD panel you've been envying :)

Comment: Looks like a hotfix has been released. https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?DownloadID=30518

Comment: Hotfix didn't work for me. Every time I reopen the Find window it defaults back to its original size, which is too wide and WAY too tall.